# number as an object, or storing properties of a number

Tags: object, properties, lua, overloading, modeling

in designing an algebraic equation modelling system, I had this dilemma: we cannot associate properties to a number, if I turn the number to a table with a field "value" for example, I can overload arithmetic operators, but not the logic operator since that only works when both operands have same metatable, while my users will compare "x" with numbers frequently.

For example, here is a minimal equation solver system:

```
x = 0
y = 0
eq1 = {function() return 2*x + 3*y end, rhs = 1 }
eq2 = {function() return 3*x + 2*y end, rhs = 2 }
p = {{x,y},{eq1, eq2}}
solve(p)
```

The "solve()" will process table "p" to get all coefficients of the equation system and rhs. However, it is essential, a user can associate properties to "x" and "y", for example, lower bound, upper bound. I tries using table,

```
x = {val=0, lb=0, ub=3}
y = {val=1,lb=3,ub=5}
....
```

and write metamethods for "x" and "y" such that arithmetic operating will act on x.val and y.val. However, in a scripting environment, we also need to compare "x" with numbers, i.e., "if x>0 then ...". And I stuck here. An ugly solution is to ask users to use x.val, y.val everywhere in modelling the equation and scripting. Does anyone here has similar need to associate properties to a number, and the number can still be used in arithmetic/logic operations?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work:

```
x = {val = 10}

mt = {}
mt.__lt = function (op1, op2)
    if (type(op1) == 'table') then a = op1.val else a = op1 end
    if (type(op2) == 'table') then b = op2.val else b = op2 end

    return a < b
end

setmetatable(x, mt)

print(x < 5)   -- prints false
print(x < 15)  -- prints true
print(x < x)   -- prints false
print(5 < x)   -- prints true
```

Of course, you would write similar methods for the other operators (`__add`, `__mul`, `__eq` and so on).

If you'd rather not use `type()`/reflection, you can use an even dirtier trick that takes advantage of the fact that unary minus is well, unary:

```
mt = {}
mt.__unm = function (num) return -(num.val) end
mt.__lt = function (a, b) return -(-a) < -(-b) end
```

Comment: Thanks, Wander, unfortunately,

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work for __eq, as the reference manual says "Lua will try a metamethod only when the values being compared are either both tables or both full userdata and they are not primitively equal." I tries print(x==10) and got false. This is rather annoying!

Comment: @user3015347 Yep, I'm afraid there's not much that can be done about that. You could consider adding your own equals method; you're probably going to need it anyway, because as it stands, `x == x` but `x ~= y` even if `y.val` is 10.

Comment: @user3015347 - Yes, the inability to redefine an equality between different types is one of the most annoying shortcomings of Lua.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather simple if you have access to the debug library, do you?

```
debug.setmetatable(0, meta)
```

meta will be the metatable of ALL numbers. This will solve your logical overloading problem.
However if you would prefer assigning properties to numbers, there is a way you could do this, I wrote a quick example on how one would do so:

local number_props = {
       {val="hi"},
       {val="hi2"}
    }

```
debug.setmetatable(0,{__index=function(self,k)return number_props[self][k]end})

print((1).val, (2).val)
```

Comment: looks simple enough! I am not sure how does this implies on performance, robustness, etc. Got to understand how Lua kernel works before having confidence on this solution.

Comment: oops, there is a deep hole in this solution. If all numbers share one metatable, there is no way to set different properties for different number, which defeats the purpose of this discussion.

Comment: @user3015347 I believe one of your core problems was logic metamethods, only working if they have same metatable. Well this way you can make that work.

Comment: Also it would be easy to achieve properties for the number 1, and totally different props for the number 2.

Comment: yes, the core problem is equality comparison, which needs both sides being table with SAME metamethod...... I cannot make this work, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @user I realize this problem, but did you see where I made the numbers contain properties?